# RSocket Java Client to access Binance websocket API

Tags: java, websocket, rsocket

I am trying to connect to Binance websocket endpoint using RSocket with Spring, but I am getting the following exception.

`java.lang.AssertionError: expectation "consumeNextWith" failed (expected: onNext(); actual: onError(java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException))`

Here is my testing code:

```
@SpringBootTest
@Slf4j
class RSocketClientIntegrationTest {

    private static RSocketRequester requester;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setupOnce(@Autowired RSocketRequester.Builder builder) {
        // given
        requester = builder
                .connectWebSocket(URI.create("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws"))
                .block();
    }

    @Test
    void shouldRetrieveStockPricesFromTheService() {
        //when
        final Flux<String> aggregatedTradeStream = requester
                .route("/bnbbtc@aggTrade")
                .retrieveFlux(String.class)
                .take(1)
                .doOnError(e -> log.error(e.toString()));

        // then
        StepVerifier.create(aggregatedTradeStream)
                .consumeNextWith(response -> {
                    assertThat(response).isNotNull();
                })
                .verifyComplete();
    }
}
```

Can I connect straight into a WebSocket endpoint using RSocket or do I have to create a RSocket server that handles the websocket and then from this proxy server I connect to the websocket?

Answer (score 1):

RSocket over WebSocket uses websocket as a transport to carry RSocket payloads.  So you can't connect to a raw WebSocket and expect anything to work.

Try testing the above program against an endpoint like

wss://rsocket-demo.herokuapp.com/rsocket

See docs at https://rsocket-demo.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Thank you for your response. You are correct. The Binance Websocket is not a RSocket endpoint, so I can not use RSocket connection.